# Alter View to change datetime to date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

How can i write an alter view statement to change a column format(datetime) to date format?

```
ALTER VIEW my_view AS  
SELECT `time` AS 'date' Date;
```

The above doesnt work but hoping to get something along those lines.
Its nots as easy as just changing the data type for tables.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to preserve the data currently stored there?

Comment: Yes, just want to remove the timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`DATE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
... AS
SELECT DATE(`time`) AS `date` FROM t;
```

Or using [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html):

```
... AS
SELECT CAST(`time` AS DATE) AS `date` FROM t;
```

Or, if your concern is presentation (rather than calculation), use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

*P.S.: I would always avoid using reserved words as identifiers (`time`, `date`, etc). They are, you know, reserved.*